# calculation of characteristic expansion time of the universe

Tags: big-bang-theory, hubble-constant

Hubble's constant is estimated at 15km/s at a distance of million light years, without considering effects of mutual gravity, relativity, etc.
I am trying to calculate the characteristic expansion time of the universe.
Its formula is given as reciprocal of the Hubble constant, because time is distance by velocity. But:

$$v=kx$$

This implies that velocity and distance are exponential functions of time and so time cannot simply be calculated by dividing 1 million light years by 15km/s.
So what am I missing? Why is the characteristic expansion time simply the reciprocal of Hubble's constant?

Comment: Please [edit] for spelling. Put capital letters at the start of sentences, names of people and the word "I", and the correct spelling is "because" not "cuz"

Comment: 15 km/s/Mlyr is somewhat off — **21** km/s/Mlyr is more correct. If you divide 1 Mlyr with 21 km/s, you get roughly 14.3 Gyr, which is pretty close to the 13.8 Gyr inferred from Planck measurements.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some remarks on the issue, straight from Ryden:

> If galaxies are currently moving away from each other, then it implies
>   they were closer together in the past. Consider a pair of galaxies
>   currently separated by a distance $r$, with a velocity $v = H_0r$
>   relative to each other. If there are no forces acting to accelerate or
>   decelerate their relative motion, then their velocity is constant, adn
>   the time that has elapsed since they were in contact is
>
> $t_0 = \frac{r}{v} = \frac{r}{H_0r} = H_0^{-1}$,
>
> independent of their current separation $r$.

Which part of this are you confused about? I can edit my answer once I better understand your question.